# Why Addition Mod 32?

Tags: algorithm-design, xor, twofish

I was looking at the [algorithm for Twofish](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Twofishalgo.svg), and I noticed that in some places a XOR is used, but in others, they use "addition modulo-32." What makes modulo-32 special? Why not always use XOR? Why not always addition mod 32?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The combination between addition modulo $2^{32}$ (not modulo $32 = 2^5$) - indicated by $\boxplus$ in the diagram - and XOR (i.e. bitwise addition modulo $2$) - indicated by $\oplus$ - makes the algorithm more non-linear.

Each of them for itself is a linear operation, but over different groups (addition in $GF(2^{32})$ vs. addition in $Z/2^{32})$, and the combination is slightly non-linear over both groups.

Why modulo $2^{32}$? This operation is already implemented in many processors (Java's `int` addition is this, for example), and this makes implementation easy and efficient.

The later Threefish cipher used in Skein takes this to a new level, its nonlinearity depending exclusively on this simple combination, in a really large number of rounds.

Comment: For the PHT at least, this answer isn't correct. They used modular addition because it could be implemented more efficiently using the `LEA` instruction to perform several operations at once. This actually decreases security very slightly, since the most significant bit is lost in the PHT (see the AES submission paper).

Comment: @forest Don't you think that a simple XOR is similarly parallelizable as the modular addition? (The question was comparing XOR with add mod $2^32$, not modular addition with some other addition.) (Also, what is PHT in this context?)

Comment: PHT refers to Pseudo-Hadamard Transform in this context. It's not that it's parallelizable so much as the fact that the `LEA` instruction is able to perform both the PHT and the subkey addition in just one clock (see section 7.4 and 7.5). For PHT over 32-bit integers $a$ and $b$, Twofish does  $a^\prime = a + b \mod 2^{32}$ and $b^\prime = a + 2b \mod 2^{32}$. Section 7.8 explains how the security is decreased (very slightly): "_The half of the PHT involving the quantity $T_0 + 2T_1$ will lose the most significant bit of $T_1$ due to the multiply by two._"